# trying to set column type in a view

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have this in a view query

```
(SELECT CAST(COUNT( *) AS NUMBER(10))
    FROM other_table ibl
    WHERE ibl.fk_id = my_table.id
)                           AS my_column
```

However Oracle still reports the column as type number with no size.

Is there any way around this? 
I want it to be number(10)

db version is 11.2

Comment: Why does it matter? Maybe you can explain why do you need it to be `NUMBER(10)`?

Comment: I have an app that validates based on column width and I cannot change that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you've just put the `CAST` in the wrong place.  Your `CAST` would need to wrap your inline subquery

In this example, `col2` is how it appears you are defining the column currently.  `col1` shows how it would need to be defined.

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  create or replace view vw_foo
  2  as
  3  select cast( (select count(*) from dual) as number(10) ) col1,
  4         (select cast( count(*) as number(10)) from dual) col2
  5*   from dual
SQL> /

View created.

SQL> desc vw_foo
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 COL1                                               NUMBER(10)
 COL2                                               NUMBER
```

Comment: Brilliant thanks, A mistake I was making on my effort close to this was putting an `as` in from of the new column name, caused oracle to reject the query.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do should work just fine, so your problem must originate somewhere else. Below is a script that I used to test this.

```
CREATE Table table1 (no1 NUMBER);
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(123);
DESC table1;
CREATE VIEW view1 AS
SELECT CAST(no1 AS NUMBER(10)) AS no2 FROM table1;
DESC view1;
```